# Extract string and assign to the variable using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a script which will go through text file and check for particular content and assign to the variable.

For example:

Text file content:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ee:27:ff:b3:d7  
          inet addr:10.0.2.45  Bcast:10.3.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe00:b3d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14045795 (14.0 MB)  TX bytes:1355632 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)  TX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)
```

I would like to check value of 'RX packets' on interface eth0 and assign value '16178' to the variable. I need to be able to extract this value from this particular block 'eth0'.

Please advise where to start?

Thank you.

Comment: assign what to the variable ?

Comment: I will have a script which need to read those values and assign to variables. Once values are assigned I will have to do some calculations on those variables. Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be an output of `ifconfig` why would you want to do this using python where as you easily do it from shell

Comment: Yes I know it looks odd. But this is only example, target data will be text file with various outputs, large file GB's of data. At the moment I am trying to figure out how to do it. How I can find what I am looking for and assign this to the variable... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to extract the value.

Try a pattern:

```
m = re.match("\W*RX packets[^:]*:(\d+)", line)
```

In a regular expression `\d` means a digit, and a `+` means one or more. You want to 'match' one or more numbers in the text. The brackets mean to capture what is found into a number, this number should be found after a specific text `RX packets:`.

You can find more details about regular expression in the [official doc.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Your code would look like:

```
data= """
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ee:27:ff:b3:d7  
          inet addr:10.0.2.45  Bcast:10.3.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe00:b3d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14045795 (14.0 MB)  TX bytes:1355632 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)  TX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)"""

import re

def findSeq(block,data):
    isInRightBlock= False
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if block in line:
            isInRightBlock= True
        m = re.match("\W*RX packets[^:]*:(\d+)", line)
        if m and isInRightBlock:
            isInRightBlock= False
            return m.group(1)


res= findSeq("eth0",data)
print res #Your Value
```

Output:

```
16178
```

**Banchemark**

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time_1 = datetime.now()
res= findSeq("eth0",data)
print('Duration: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time_1))

from datetime import datetime
start_time_2 = datetime.now()
re.search(r'eth0.*?RX packets:(\d+)',data,re.DOTALL).group(1)
print('Duration: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time_2))
```

**Output:**

```
Duration: 0:00:00.000547
Duration: 0:00:00.000344
```

**NT:** You can optimize the way it checks the right block.

Comment: That's great help, thanks. Would you be able to explain this line "m = re.match("\W*RX packets[^:]*:\D*(\d+)", line)" - how this regex is pulling only value that I am looking for and not e.g. whole like? Thank you.

Comment: That's was very useful. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Taha: this kind of benchmark doesn't proof nothing because the amount of data is very small and you need to repeat the search 10000x at least to obtain something significant. As an experience, try to invert the order of tests and see the new result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, check his comment in the original post "This is only an example, target data will be text file with various outputs, large file GB's of data.". I tried to compare with the other right answers to stress the point of speediness.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using Regex as shown; `eth0.*?` specifies that packet blonging to **eth0** should be extracted, `RX packets:` specifies digits following **RX packets:** needs to be extracted and `(\d)` groups extracted digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> a="""eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ee:27:ff:b3:d7  
...           inet addr:10.0.2.45  Bcast:10.3.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
...           inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe00:b3d7/64 Scope:Link
...           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
...           RX packets:16178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
...           TX packets:8559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
...           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
...           RX bytes:14045795 (14.0 MB)  TX bytes:1355632 (1.3 MB)
... 
... lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
...           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
...           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
...           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
...           RX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
...           TX packets:666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
...           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
...           RX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)  TX bytes:72748 (72.7 KB)"""
>>> re.search(r'eth0.*?RX packets:(\d+)',a,re.DOTALL).group(1)
'16178'
```

Comment: +1 note that you can reduce the amount of "non-greedy walk" using this kind of pattern: `(?m)^eth0\s(?:.+\n)*?\s+RX packets:([0-9]+)` that is non-greedy line by line instead of character by character.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.findall('eth0.*?RX packets:(\d+)',x,re.DOTALL)
['16178']
```